# WSImport WSDL artifacts in same package

Tags: wsimport

I have a WSDL which has 3 schemas say Schema 1, Schema 2 and Schema 3 .

```
Schema 1 - Target_namespace_1
Schema 2 - Target_namespace_2
Schema 3 - Target_namespace_3
```

When i run the WSImport in cmd line on the WSDL file , it creates java artifacts in folders namely

```
Target_namespace_1, Target_namespace_2,Target_namespace_3.
```

This WSDL is used in another project and all the artifacts appear in a single package.

I have tried using the options in wsimport.exe but still not able to generate all the packages in a single package. Any advise in this regard will be very helpful

Comment: So are you trying to use the same WSDL for services that run in, for example, 3 places? Or are you trying to manage 3 WSDLs from service that run in the same app? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

Assumed below WSDL includes multiple XSDs with different namespaces calling wsimport this way:

```
 wsimport.exe -d C:/temp/generatedClasses -s C:/temp/sourceFiles C:/temp/myWsdl.wsdl
```

will give you a package structure like described in your question (e.g. own package per namespace)

You can use the parameter -p this way:

```
wsimport.exe -d C:/temp/generatedClasses -s C:/temp/sourceFiles -p blob.der.bob C:/temp/myWsdl.wsdl
```

And any output resides in the same package (your .java files would reside in C:/temp/sourceFiles/blob/der/bob)